# Change value variable with search/filter dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I have this search/filter dropdown which takes the array of the `allNameMuseums()` method as values, ie ["ACQUARIUM", "Museo2", "Museo3"].

```
<h2>Search/Filter Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu, and use the input field to search for a specific dropdown link.</p>
<div class="dropdown">
   <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
   <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
   </div>
</div>
```

I have the global variable `name`, which every time I click on one of the values of Search/Filter Dropdown the name takes that value, ie if I click on ACQUARIO then `name` will be ACQUARIO.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    allNameMuseums().forEach(function(item) { // ITERAZIONE
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").innerHTML += '<a onclick="fnclick(this)">' + item + '</a>';
    })
});

var name; //globle variable so you can access in your method

function fnclick(obj) {
    name = obj.innerHTML;
    console.log(name);
}


function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            a[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            a[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

function allNameMuseums() {
    return ["ACQUARIO", "Museo2", "Museo3"];
}
```

I have two asynchronous methods, `specificoMuseo(name)` and `allMuseums()`, and a variable `var data = proof;` that takes the result of the `allMuseums()` method. I want that when I click on ACQUARIO of Search / Filter Dropdown the variable 'data' takes as input the result of `specificoMuseo("ACQUARIO")`.

```
specificoMuseo(name).then(proof2 => {
    allMuseums().then(proof => {
        var data = proof;
    });
});
```

Comment: what do you mean with "the variable 'data' takes as input" ?

Comment: var data = result of specificoMuseo("ACQUARIO")

Comment: Why do you need it ? I mean what is the difference between do that inside and outside the promise ?

Comment: specificoMuseo(name) and allMuseums() are asynchronous methods, to take their values I need to put data inside the promise

Answer (score 0):

You can use `await` keyword instead of the promise:

```
var data = await specificoMuseo("ACQUARIO"); // This is like proof2
var data2 = await allMuseums(); // This is like proof
```

If you want to run this process in parallel because any promise depends of each other, you can use `Primise.all` method:

```
Promise.all([specificoMuseo("ACQUARIO"), allMuseums()])
  .then(([proof2, proof]) => {
    // ...
  })
```

With the `await` keyword:

```
var [proof2, proof] = Promise.all([specificoMuseo("ACQUARIO"), allMuseums()])
```

**EDIT:**

when you click on "ACQUARIO" this function is gonna be fired `fnclick(this)`

```
function fnclick(obj) {
    name = obj.innerHTML;
    var [proof2, proof] = Promise.all([specificoMuseo(name), allMuseums()])
    console.log(name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you know how can i do whenI want to click on ACQUARIO of Search / Filter Dropdown the variable 'data' will be the result of specificoMuseo("ACQUARIO")?

Comment: Check the **EDIT**

Comment: In this way the variable data will not return the result of the method specificoMuseo(ACQUARIO).

Comment: Could you show the `specificoMuseo(ACQUARIO)` function ?